# Many to many relationship join table is not saving data

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have 2 classes Users/Blips that I am joining through a User_blips join table. But when I submit a Blip in my form it does not save any data to the join table. Can you help me figure out why? (As an additional question, even when i put "sentence_id" in the strong params it still throws an error saying it's unpermitted)

Blip model:

```
has_many :users, through: :user_blips
has_many :user_blips, dependent: :nullify
```

User model:

```
has_many :blipped_users, through: :user_blips, source: :blip
has_many :user_blips, dependent: :nullify
```

Blip create method:

```
def create
@sentence = Sentence.find params[:sentence_id]
@blip = Blip.new blip_params
@blip.sentence = @sentence

 if @blip.save
  flash[:success] = "Blip created successfully"
  redirect_to root_path
 else
  flash[:alert] = "Your blip was not created"
  redirect_to root_path
 end
end

def blip_params
 params.require(:blip).permit(:body)
end
```

Console message on Blip Create:

```
Started POST "/sentences/1/blips" for 127.0.0.1 at 2015-02-22 12:13:58     -0800
Processing by BlipsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓",     "authenticity_token"=>"bsXf7SqWJxv2XjOy79RDvDcpJTZnFJhJj+R50CzBFPyqbHsgo5jt    vdrpFuOjHmZ0q+pIyT5tPdR0Ia2cXCJcGQ==", "blip"=>{"'sentence_id'"=>"1",     "body"=>"ddsdsds"}, "sentence_id"=>"1"}
Sentence Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "sentences".* FROM "sentences" WHERE     "sentences"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 1]]
Unpermitted parameter: 'sentence_id'

(0.2ms)  BEGIN
SQL (0.4ms)  INSERT INTO "blips" ("body", "sentence_id", "created_at",     "updated_at") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4) RETURNING "id"  [["body", "ddsdsds"],     ["sentence_id", 1], ["created_at", "2015-02-22 20:13:58.255772"],     ["updated_at", "2015-02-22 20:13:58.255772"]]
(0.4ms)  COMMIT
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 11ms (ActiveRecord: 1.3ms)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use an `has_and_belongs_to_many` `association` with the join table `blips_users` [rails guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association)

User model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :blips
```

Blip model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :users
```

Migration:

```
rails generate migration create_blips_users user_id:integer blip_id:integer; rake db:migrate
```

Controller:

```
def create
  user = User.first # or maybe current_user
  user.blips << Blip.new(create_params)
end

def create_params
  params.require(:blip).permit(:body, :sentence_id)
end
```

This will create the `blip` and its corresponding association with the `user`

Comment: Thanks. I created a blips_users table using a migration (t.belongs_to :blip t.belongs_to :user)

And when I save a new blip it still does not link the two together. After saving blip, in console: 

b = Blip.last
b.users  returns a blank array of user_IDs. Any idea what I missed? I did change the relationships in the models as you suggested.

Comment: `user  = User.first` `blip = Blip.first` `user.blips << blip` should create the `association`

Comment: That worked! It still says sentence_id is not permitted though.. It's not affecting the functionality but I really wonder why.